# Accessing shared ptr from shared ptr of array

Tags: c++, c++14, shared-ptr, shared-memory, unique-ptr

I have function which is copying some value to objects i'll pass.

So, Something like this

```
void functionReturnObjects(int* ptr);
```

I'll call above function like this

```
std::shared_ptr<int> sp( new int[10], std::default_delete<int[]>() );
functionReturnObjects(sp.get());  => so this will copy int objects to sp.
```

Now, I want to take individual shared ptr from the above 10 and want to make separate copy or want to shared it with some other shared ptr.

So something like

```
std::shared_ptr<int> newCopy = sp[1] ==> This is not working I am just showing what I want.
```

Basically I want to transfer ownership from 10 shared pointer to new individual shared ptr without allocating new memory.

Please let me know if the questions is not clear.

Comment: If your "individual" stared pointer does not share ownership with the other sared pointers then you have to allocate something else for it to share that the other pointers are not sharing.

Comment: No, don't read a "tutorial". Buy a proper book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std::shared_ptr`'s aliasing constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) (overload #8):

> ```
> template< class Y > 
> shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r, element_type *ptr );
> ```

```
std::shared_ptr<int> newCopy(sp, sp.get() + 1);
```

This will make `newCopy` and `sp` share ownership of the entire array created with `new int[10]`, but `newCopy.get()` will point to the second element of said array.

In C++17 this can instead look like the following if you happen to find it more readable:

```
std::shared_ptr newCopy(sp, &sp[1]);
```